# Invoking photoshop droplet from php

Tags: php, photoshop, shell-exec

I'm trying to develop a webapp where users upload images and afterwards they can sort the images.

The images are manipulated by a Photoshop droplet (color- and lens correction). When I invoke the droplet from command-line everything is working fine. However when my webapp (Apache+PHP+MySql) invokes the droplet with shell_exec() the droplet starts up but doesn't do anything. I tried to run `httpd.exe`, `droplet.exe`, `photoshop.exe` as administrator. And Ive tried to allow the Apache service to interact with desktop. But nothing helps.

Anyone has some ideas?

Here is the PHP:

```
shell_exec("D:\\scripts\\icon-01.exe D:\\users\\pmla\\DSC_0055.NEF");
```

And Here is the error I'm seeing:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\BitNami\wampstack-5.4.10-0\apache2\htdocs\test.php on line 34
```

Comment: you probably made an error calling the droplet. which return code does it give? also please double check the commandline, not saying you did however a common mistake is to not properly encode parameters.

Comment: Could you post the results of `var_dump(shell_exec("your command here"));`. Also is PHP running in safe mode?

Comment: hi there the call is shell_exec("D:\\scripts\\icon-01.exe D:\\users\\pmla\\DSC_0055.NEF"); when i call the php script from command line php myscript.phh every thing is okay. The shell_exec doest return unless i force quit droplet process then il get "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\BitNami\wampstack-5.4.10-0\apache2\htdocs\test.php on line 34"

Comment: did you double check php user's permissions for those directories? also the temp directory as set by php.ini?  Have you been able to do this before?